# Identification of switch type casing type or housing type

Tags: switches, identification

I don't know what or how to identify this switch.

[image: a picture of a switch on my knee]

Its dimensions are:

29.5mm by 25 by 21.5 tall. It has a lug for a screw on the side you can't see it is actuated by a pin on a separate housing

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Stupidly I hadn't looked at another image I had which clearly stated 'XE2SP' which promptly gave me the manufacturer and terminology.

SCHNEIDER ELECTRIC / TELEMECANIQUE - XE2SP2151 - CONTACT BLOCK

[On Farnells website](http://uk.farnell.com/schneider-electric-telemecanique/xe2sp2151/contact-block/dp/8730300)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an Eaton or Cutler-Hammer [safety switch](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1470496.pdf), though it's really difficult to guess from the limited information.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

> Can somebody let me know what form factor this is

In EE (and physics apparently) form factor is defined as: -

> The ratio of the RMS value to the absolute mean of a sinusoidal wave
>   (especially to that of an alternating current)

Taken from [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/form_factor)

If you are wanting to know the form factor as defined by EE guys then it doesn't apply to a switch - it's to do with electrical signals.

Comment: Point taken but not very helpful. How about modifying the question or offering better terminology

Comment: I have modified the title for you so it is less 'ambiguos'...

Comment: @PaulSullivan - how about you define what you mean by form-factor because the only meaning I understand is as stated in my answer.

Comment: Form Factor n. "the physical size and shape of a piece of computer hardware" http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/94902/Form_Factor

Comment: Another definition from wiki (computing) says "form factor" relates to the motherboard: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_form_factor

Comment: @Andyaka Sure. ATX form factor, for example. It basically means shape, size or some other physical dimension (or conformity to a standard that defines those). Loose term, but pretty common IME.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Maybe not east a few thousand miles OR maybe I've led a closeted life - always wondered what all them monks were doing locking up at night LOL.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany's exactly right - the term "form factor" is used commonly for all manner of physical objects. One excellent example is the (now obsolete) "full height form factor" for Winchester hard drives.

Comment: @TDHofstetter so, should I just throw away the definition from wikipedia which, has it happens, I also felt was correct before I checked wiki - Spehro's definition of form factor is for computer hardware and by the sounds of it so is your winchester hard drive so, should I also assume that the switch in question is for use in a computer? Is that what you are trying to convince me of? Not a common version of the term used in the UK I might add.

Comment: @Andyaka, the definition from Wikipedia is only incomplete because it pertains only to "Computer form factor", its heading. The more nonspecialized term "form factor" is also applied to car tires, kitchen appliances, nearly anything with a somewhat standardized shape & footprint. The contact block in question is almost certainly **not** for use in computers - it's more suited to an industrial environment where it may be used to control motors or relay banks.

Comment: @TDHofstetter I'm not sure where Vermont is but, in the UK the term "form factor" is rarely heard of. I answered the question with a definition from Wiki and you seem to want an argument about a lonely old question that received me a downvote for trying to be helpful so please, do us both a favour and leave it be.